# Using Power shell active users count in a site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell

Using Power shell how to get active users count in a site?

I tried the following code but not getting the result

```
function Get-WebServiceConnections()
{
  $results = @{}
  $perfmon = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter
  $perfmon.CategoryName = "Web Service"
  $perfmon.CounterName = "Current Connections"

  $cat = new-object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("Web Service")
  $instances = $cat.GetInstanceNames()

  foreach ($instance in $instances)
  {
    $perfmon.InstanceName = $instance
    $results.Add($instance, $perfmon.NextValue())
  }
  write-output $results
}
```

(Refernce  -  http://poshcode.org/1146)

Comment: Tested on my local machine where IIS is active and publishes some clickonce application and it returns the correct value of active user sessions

Comment: I am new in power shell ,I dont know how to execute it. Please explain me !!

Comment: copy and paste the code in your powershell console and after type `Get-WebServiceConnections` and hit enter. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got the result but am getting all count as zero (We are using session state mode as stateserver)

Comment: Sorry i sorted the issue thanks for your help